# how to calculate rolling volatility

Tags: arrays, r

I am trying to design a function that will calculate 30 day rolling volatility.
I have a file with 3 columns: date, and daily returns for 2 stocks.

How can I do this? I have a problem in summing the first 30 entries to get my vol.

Edit:

So it will read an excel file, with 3 columns: a date, and daily returns.

daily.ret = read.csv("abc.csv")

e.g.  date   stock1     stock2
  01/01/2000   0.01         0.02

etc etc, with years of data. I want to calculate rolling 30 day annualised vol.
This is my function:

```
calc_30day_vol = function()
{
stock1 = abc$stock1^2
stock2 = abc$stock1^2
j = 30
approx_days_in_year = length(abc$stock1)/10
vol_1 = 1: length(a1) 
vol_2 = 1: length(a2)

for (i in 1 : length(a1))
{
vol_1[j] = sqrt( (approx_days_in_year / 30 ) * rowSums(a1[i:j])

vol_2[j] = sqrt( (approx_days_in_year / 30 ) * rowSums(a2[i:j])


j = j + 1
}

}
```

So stock1, and stock 2 are the squared daily returns from the excel file, needed to calculate vol. Entries 1-30 for vol_1 and vol_2 are empty since we are calculating 30 day vol. I am trying to use the rowSums function to sum the squared daily returns for the first 30 entries, and then move down the index for each iteration. 
So from day 1-30, day 2-31, day 3-32, etc, hence why I have defined "j".

I'm new  at R, so apologies if this sounds rather silly.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried to add a little more detail for explanation.

Comment: If you write '[r] rolling' in the search box at the top, you get all these answers http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+rolling as this is a pretty common question.

Comment: This will download prices for SPY, calculate daily log returns, and then calculate a 30 day rolling standard deviation: `library(quantmod); getSymbols("SPY"); runSD(ROC(SPY), n=30)`

Comment: In addition to @GSee's suggestion, you could use `TTR::volatility`.

Comment: @GSee: (or Joshua or Dirk) Would someone either put up an answer or vote to close as a duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started.

First I have to create some data that look like you describe

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("SPY", "DIA"), src='yahoo')
m <- merge(ROC(Ad(SPY)), ROC(Ad(DIA)), all=FALSE)[-1, ]
dat <- data.frame(date=format(index(m), "%m/%d/%Y"), coredata(m))
tmpfile <- tempfile()
write.csv(dat, file=tmpfile, row.names=FALSE)
```

Now I have a csv with data in your very specific format.
Use `read.zoo` to read csv and then convert to an xts object (there are lots of ways to read data into R.  See [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html))

```
r <- as.xts(read.zoo(tmpfile, sep=",", header=TRUE, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
# each column of r has daily log returns for a stock price series
# use `apply` to apply a function to each column.
vols.mat <- apply(r, 2, function(x) {
    #use rolling 30 day window to calculate standard deviation.
    #annualize by multiplying by square root of time
    runSD(x, n=30) * sqrt(252)
})
#`apply` returns a `matrix`; `reclass` to `xts`
vols.xts <- reclass(vols.mat, r) #class as `xts` using attributes of `r`
tail(vols.xts)
#           SPY.Adjusted DIA.Adjusted
#2012-06-22    0.1775730    0.1608266
#2012-06-25    0.1832145    0.1640912
#2012-06-26    0.1813581    0.1621459
#2012-06-27    0.1825636    0.1629997
#2012-06-28    0.1824120    0.1630481
#2012-06-29    0.1898351    0.1689990

#Clean-up
unlink(tmpfile)
```